# MongoDB and ElasticSearch spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kotlin

I am using Spring boot 2.0.0.Release with gradle and webflux written in Kotlin and I am trying to make ReactiveMongoDB and Elasticsearch work together, I also have JWT implementation. So to validate the AuthenticationToken I implemented `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` like below:

```
@Component
class UserAuthenticationManager(@Inject private val service: UserService,
                                @Inject private val encoder: PasswordEncoder) : ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Mono<Authentication> {
        return service.findByUsernameWithPassword(authentication.name)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .filter { u -> encoder.matches(authentication.credentials as String, u.password) }
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer<User> { Mono.error<User>(BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials")) })
                .map { u -> AuthenticationToken(u.id, u.username, u.password!!, u.roles.map { SimpleGrantedAuthority(it.name) }) }
    }

}
```

and to enable reactive mongodb repository I did this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(
        basePackages = ["com.example.package.repository.**.nosql"],
        excludeFilters = [
            ComponentScan.Filter(
                    type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                    value = [ElasticsearchRepository::class]
            )
        ]
)
class DatabaseConfiguration
```

Also I configured ElasticSearchRepositories like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(
        basePackages = ["com.example.package.repository.**.search"],
        excludeFilters = [
            ComponentScan.Filter(
                    type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                    value = [ReactiveMongoRepository::class]
            )
        ]
)
class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun elasticsearchTemplate(client: Client, builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder): ElasticsearchTemplate {
        return ElasticsearchTemplate(client, CustomEntityMapper(builder.createXmlMapper(false).build()))
    }

    inner class CustomEntityMapper(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : EntityMapper {

        init {
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun mapToString(`object`: Any): String {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(`object`)
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun <T> mapToObject(source: String, clazz: Class<T>): T {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the `gradle bootRun` it throws exception below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [8], rejecting [8]
    at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime$AvailableProcessorsHolder.setAvailableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:51)
    at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime.setAvailableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:87)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.setAvailableProcessors(Netty4Utils.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.<init>(Netty4Transport.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.lambda$getTransports$0(Netty4Plugin.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:133)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.buildClient(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.elasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4eba21d.CGLIB$elasticsearchClient$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4eba21d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc4f5c6f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4eba21d.elasticsearchClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 137 common frames omitted
```

While debugging, I found out, `setAvailableProcessors` method is called twice in `NettyRuntime`, first for `MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration` and second for `ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration` where I get exception. Also I found out, if I remove my implementation of `UserAuthenticationManager`, `MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration` doesn't call `setAvailableProcessors` method so everything works fine because it is called once by `ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration`. Why `MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration` cares about `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`. I really confused. How can I fix this problem without removing `UserAuthenticationManager` implementation?

Any helps?

**Solution:**
With help of @RomanDzhadan I found the way of preventing reactive mongo db to check Netty available processors.
The problem was this Bean in `MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration`

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public MongoClient reactiveStreamsMongoClient(MongoProperties properties,
Environment environment,
ObjectProvider<List<MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer>> builderCustomizers) {
    ReactiveMongoClientFactory factory = new ReactiveMongoClientFactory(properties,
            environment, builderCustomizers.getIfAvailable());
    this.mongo = factory.createMongoClient(this.settings);
    return this.mongo;
}
```

So I solved it by having my own bean definition of MongoClient for example something like this:

```
@Bean
fun mongoClient(): MongoClient {
    logger.debug("Configuring mongo client")
    return MongoClients.create(mongoProperties.determineUri())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manage configuration beans by yourself. Spring Auto Configuration - always full of pitfalls. Especially, when you trying to use more then 1 implementation of spring data. (in your case it's elasticsearch and mongo).

Frameworks can't do everything for you. So, I will recommend to setup it explicitly.

- **Cons:** 1 or 2 extra classes with beans creation.
- **Pros:** Much more control and understanding of how your application works

Comment: I really like simplicity. I will do your suggestion if I have to but before that, I would like to know the reason, I even debugged `EnableReactiveMongoRepositories` but I really couldn't understand what's going on?

Comment: what elasticsearch version do you use? and what version of spring-data-elasticsearch?

Comment: I am using `6.1.2` for elasticsearch and `spring-data-elasticsearch` will be loaded by Spring Boot version `2.0.0.Release` dependency management `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.M8`

Comment: Try to override elasticsearch version in pom.xml or in gradle.  [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.1.2)

Comment: to what version?
Also I appreciate giving me solutions but I need first to know about the reason behind this. in the worse scenario I will load the bean manually as you suggested or set `System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");` to avoid elasticsearch check for available processors. Do you have any idea why am I getting this error?

Comment: This one [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.1.2). Elasticsearch was built on top of Netty. Webflux has it's own Netty version. You need to make sure that you use the same version of Elasticsearch in your project as Elasticsearch server. Elasticsearch announced breaking changes in next versions. Currently, Spring's data implementation supports only `transport-client` (which is legacy). You can read more details here: [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/_motivations_around_a_new_java_client.html)

Comment: In other words, using elasticsearch-spring-data - it's a bad idea. Java High Level REST Client will replace transport-client very soon.